# Template is being parsed, data is correct, but no elements are added to DOM

Tags: ember.js

I have a handlebars template being displayed as an `outlet`. When I open the route for the first time, the table is shown with the expected data. But whenever I transition to this route from another route, using `tranisitionToRoute`, the elements are not added to the DOM.

I have added logging to the template, so I know that the data is there and the template is being processed, but no elements are added to the DOM. This is the top-level template:

```
{{hbsdebug "xxxx"}}
{{log this}}
{{log this.content}}
<article>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <div id="legend" class="">
                <legend class="">{{capitalize pluralHuman}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge">{{entriesLength}} records</span>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        {{#if allowDeleteAll}}
                            <a {{action destroyAllRecords}} class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Delete All {{capitalize pluralHuman}}</a>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#linkTo newRoute class="btn btn-primary"}}<i class="icon-plus"></i> Add {{capitalize singularHuman}}{{/linkTo}}
                    </div>
                </legend>
            </div>

            {{view SettingsApp.MessageTrayView id="message-tray-view"}}

            {{#if isUpdating}}
                {{mylog "Loading data!!!" null}}
                <div style="text-align:center;"><br/><br/><img src="images/circular_loader.gif" /><br/><br/>Loading the list of {{pluralHuman}}...</div>
            {{else}}
                {{#if entriesLength}}
                  {{mylog "Showing outlet > entriesLength >" entriesLength}}
                  {{outlet}}
                {{else}}
                  {{mylog "Showing partial empty_list" null}}
                  {{partial "empty_list"}}
                {{/if}}
            {{/if}}
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</article>
```

This is my `outlet`:

```
{{hbsdebug "services/index"}}
{{mylog "services/index > this"    this }}
{{mylog "services/index > content" content }}
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Startnode</th>
        <th>Nextnode</th>
        <th>JumpIfBusy</th>
        <th>JumpIfNoAnswer</th>
        <th style="width: 36px;"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {{#each model}}
    {{log this}}
    {{mylog "services/index.each > this"  this  }}
        <tr class="odd-even">
            <td>{{#linkTo controller.showRoute this}}{{grayOutIfUndef2 properties.name formattedName "(undefined)"}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
            <td>{{grayOutIfUndef formattedStartnode}}</td>
            <td>{{grayOutIfUndef formattedNextnode}}</td>
            <td>{{grayOutIfUndef formattedJumpIfBusy}}</td>
            <td>{{grayOutIfUndef formattedJumpIfNoAnswer}}</td>
            <td>
                <a {{action startEditing this}}><i class="icon-pencil"></i><a/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a {{action destroyRecord this}}><i class="icon-remove"></i><a/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

(the helpers `hbsdebug`, `log` and `mylog` are just there to see in the console that the template is being processed. I am so confused that I am logging using different methods)

This is the template from which I am "transitioning back" to the table:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="legend" class="">
            <p class="form-action-title">{{grayOutIfUndef formattedName}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-content-wrapper-fixed">
            {{ propPartial "showPartial" }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" {{action startEditing this}}><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
            <a class="btn" {{action backToList}}><i class="icon-th-list"></i> Back to list</a>
            <a class="btn pull-right" {{action destroyRecord this}}><i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove</a>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this is the `backToList` action:

```
backToList: function () {
    console.log('backToList > indexRoute=%o', this.indexRoute);
    this.transitionToRoute(this.indexRoute);
}
```

Where `indexRoute` is a string, i.e. `services.index`.

What could the problem be? What could be preventing ember to properly update the DOM?

### UPDATE

Since I am protecting the outlet with an `{{if isUpdating}}` (to show a spinner while data is being requested from the backend) I have verified that the problem occurs in certain situations. There are two possible "rendering sequences":

1. The index route is selected
2. The data is requested from the backend (`isUpdating` -> `true`)
3. Spinner is shown
4. The data is received (`isUpdating` -> `false`)
5. The outlet path is followed ("Showing outlet")
6. The outlet is processed, and the DOM updated

This is working fine. But when re-selecting the index route, the order is changed:

1. The index route is selected
2. The data is requested (`isUpdating` -> `true`)
3. The outlet is processed (even though the data `isUpdating`!!)
4. Then ember realizes that another path should be followed, and the spinner is shown
5. The data is received (`isUpdating` -> `false`)
6. Now the "Showing outlet" path in the template is followed, but the `outlet` is not really processed, so the DOM is not updated anymore.

So I guess the important questions are:

- (step 3) Why is the outlet processed even though `isUpdating` is true?
- (step 6) Why is ember telling me that the outlet is being shown, but it is not really processing the outlet?

Comment: how does your transitionToRoute code look like?

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can think of could be that your `services.index` route needs some content, so when doing `this.transitionToRoute('services.index');` without passing along the model/content the transition would succeed but no content is displayed. So continuing guessing you need to pass along also some content/model to be used, like `this.transitionToRoute('services.index', this.get('content'));` or whatever content your `services.index` route needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not think so, because I am transitioning to an index. And, as said, the data is *correct*, and it is being *properly* processed. It simply does not appear in the DOM, not even the table headers! It is not a matter of wrongly set-up data. It is something else, but I do not know what.

Comment: And I have verified it does not only happen when following the `backToList` path: requesting the same index again (for example, by clicking on the `services` navigation link while being on the `show service detail` template), also does not display anything. The whole dynamic behaviour is ok (data being requested from the backend, etc), but once the template is rendered, the DOM is not updated.